# Joss & Struts issue. Where should I put the breakpoint?

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, debugging, struts-1

I'm having a problem and I've been following the code and putting breakpoints but I'm quite lost.

In struts we have :

```
<action
    path="/inici"
    forward="/llistasignants.do?method=blank"/>

<action
    path = "/llistasignants" 
    type = "com.ajmataro.gestsigdec.action.LlistasignantsAction" 
    name = "LlistasignantsForm" 
    scope = "request" 
    parameter = "method" > 
   <forward name="ok" path="/gestsigdec.Llistasignants.page"/> 
   <forward name="okModal" path="/gestsigdec.Llistasignants.page.modal"/>
```

So what I'm guessing is: I go to `inici.do` which looks for `LlistasignantsForm`  then executes `LlistasignantsAction` and loads `Llistasignants.jsp` (as is defined in tiles-def).

The thing is on the working project the first breakpoint to stop at is on `LlistasignantsForm` whilst on my project the first breakpoint is on `LlistasignantsAction`. I cannot see why.

I followed manuals and guides regarding basic flow of struts and even captured one of the devs for two minutes, all I got was "the form goes first"... except it doesn't.

Any idea/suggestion where should I put the breakpoints to find my error?

Comment: Not clear what you're asking. What's the actual problem? When does it happen?

Comment: At the start of the application. Mine crashes, original project does not. Since is so entangled I cannot put the whole thing here to discuss, that's why I put it so abstract; and why I'm asking where to put the damn breakpoints because I cannot find the issue.

Comment: More info, see if that's more clear.  Both projects call ActionForward and in both cases method=blank.  Both have this declaration on the Action.java:  public ActionForward blank(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception   but in mine the ActionForm comes Null.  I don't see what I'm doing wrong and I don't know where to put the breakpoints to follow the flow and find the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Finally on of the main programmer decided to sit by it and fixed the issue.
Although I was watching the whole time I have no idea how he sorted it out...

Anyway, sorry for the time wasted.